# Dot in front of variables in make files

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am not able to figure out what does a dot `.` in front of a variable in makefile does. For e.g.:

```
SOURCEDIRS = . $(PROJECTDIRS) $(TARGET_DIRS_CONCAT)
vpath %.c $(SOURCEDIRS)
```

It would be great if someone could tell me. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally it just refers to your current directory.

I.e. If you were on a linux machine, and you `cd /home/user/Darth` and run `ls .`, you should see the contents of the the folder Darth. So in this case, it looks like it's just including the current directory that you're in into the `SOURCEDIRS`.